# How to change insertion text (cursor) for NStextField? for os x swift 2

Tags: nstextfield

the most relevant code i found was
**let fieldEditor = self.window?.fieldEditor(true, forObject: textField) as! NSTextView?
fieldEditor!.insertionPointColor = NSColor.redColor()**
but doesn't work because field editor is nil i tried this using in subclass of textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind found the answer by extending NSTextField class and calling the function manually

```
extension NSTextField {
   public func customizeCaretColor(caretColor: NSColor) {
      let fieldEditor = self.window?.fieldEditor(true, forObject: self) as! NSTextView
      fieldEditor.insertionPointColor = caretColor
   }
}
```

Comment: When I cast NSTextField to NSTextView it breaks for me